# CORS cookie with domain field is setting only in Firefox using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I am not able to set cookie when `domain` filed is added using cross site request. I am trying to achieve that by calling request through jquery ajax.

Is it possible to get it working in other browsers than firefox?

**Some request Headers:**

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Length:55
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:53862
Origin:http://localhost:54265
Referer:http://localhost:54265/
```

**Response Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, origin, content-type, accept, Proxy-Connection
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:54265
Set-Cookie:Auth=l_hash=123456&user=xyzl&remember_me=false; expires=Fri, 18 Jan 2013 13:42:10 GMT; domain=localhost; path=/
```

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: apiHost + "api/account/login/",
    data: $("#loginBarForm").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    crossDomain: true,

    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
});
```

Everything is fine in firefox. Chrome is not setting cookie. Only if domain field is removed all is working on every browser. I can see that in next request (after setting cookie) that cookie appears in header. Example from firefox request after response setting cookie (when response had domain field):

```
Cookie: Auth=l_hash=123456&user=xyz&remember_me=false
```

Comment: Are you sure `localhost` is a valid domain for `Set-Cookie` header? According to [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), it must contain at least one "embedded" dot. FireFox may implement this in a less restrictive way. Try your IP-address instead.

Comment: @Stan Thank you so much, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem can be with `localhost`, which is not a valid domain for `Set-Cookie` header. According to [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), it must contain at least one "embedded" dot. FireFox may implement this in a less restrictive way. Try your IP-address instead.

Comment: Simply replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem, and it turned out that the browser settings were blocking third-party cookies (Chrome > Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Block third-party cookies and site data).  Allowing the cookies resolved the problem!

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem after hours of frustration!  Only in my case, I had Firefox blocking third-party cookies, and Chrome allowing them.

Comment: Also Google will start phasing out third-party cookies from Q1 2024 : https://www.techcircle.in/2023/05/19/google-will-start-phasing-out-third-party-cookies-from-q1-2024